# How do I remove an error on a hidden field?

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I am validating a hidden field, but unlike a normal field, the error does not disappear since I am assuming you can't bind keyup on a hidden field to recheck if there was something entered, which, from what I read is what Parsley does.

So I need to remove it manually. I know of this method, `window.ParsleyUI.removeError(parsleyInstance, name);` just not sure what the parsleyInstance I would pass in is and then `name`, name of what?

Here is the relevant code.

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" data-parsley-group="eventinfo" value="0" id="ActivityCount" data-parsley-min="1" data-parsley-error-message="Please select at least one activity">

<script>
var actCountParsley = $("#ActivityCount").parsley();

window.ParsleyUI.removeError(actCountParsley, 'min');

$('#EventForm').parsley({
    successClass: "has-success",
    errorClass: "has-error",
    classHandler: function(el) {
        return el.$element.closest(".form-group");
    },
    errorsWrapper: '<span class="help-inline hideHelp"></span>',
    errorTemplate: "<span></span>"
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsleyInstance` is an instance of the object ParsleyField, created for each field to be validated. You can get the instance of ParsleyField like this:

```
var hiddenParsleyField = $("#myHiddenField").parsley();
// displays the object
console.log(hiddenParsleyField);

// displays the input element
console.log(hiddenParsleyField.$element);
```

Note that this will work after you bind parsley to your form (ie: `$("#myForm").parsley()`).

As to `name`, it will be the name of the constraint. Something like `required`, `notblank`, `min`, `min`, `remote` if you are using a remote validator, etc.

To remove the error message you would do something like this:

```
var hiddenParsleyField = $("#myHiddenField").parsley();
window.ParsleyUI.removeError(hiddenParsleyField, 'required');
```

If you can't manage to get your code working with this information, please post your html and js code.

---

<sub>Edit after adding code to the question</sub>

Your issue is that you are defining a "custom" error message with

```
data-parsley-error-message="Please select at least one activity"
```

and then you are trying to remove the message with

```
window.ParsleyUI.removeError(actCountParsley, 'min');
```

This don't match. In your input you need to set the message with: `data-parsley-min-message` (that is, use `min` instead of `error`).

Besides that, as the code you posted, you are removing the message when it's not present. See [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/dunggz96/) with an example.

Comment: was hoping it would work, but didn't appear to. The console.log showed correctly tho. I have updated my question with the code used.

Comment: @KrunchMuffin Check the updated answer and related jsfiddle. If the issue persists with this information, please post a fiddle.

Comment: Ok, it's working now. Thanks for helping out. BTW, is this int he docs anywhere? I don't find the docs are that good for more advanced stuff.

Comment: I think the documentation amongst most open source projects (so it's not a Parsley problem only) is not good enough. I also believe it's quite dificult, with all the contributers and features, to write a detailed documentation. Well, that's why we are here in SO : )